# Surround array on paste Sublime

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, paste, surround

I would like to set my sublime up to enter a mode where when I paste a set of data looking like this:

```
1234567 This is code 1
2345678 This is code 2
3456789 This is code 3
```

It will end up like this:

```
['1234567', 'This is code1'],
['2345678', 'This is code2'],
['3456789', 'This is code3'],
```

Is there any way to easily do this using a hot key to switch in and out of my "special paste mode" or even a way to create a snippet that will edit the selection changing it. Heck, at this point even a simple find/replace regex will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this looks exciting.

Creating a "special paste mode"—which would have to involve a custom plugin and regular expressions anyway—sounds awfully complicated when you can just [use a snippet substitution](https://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html?highlight=snippets#substitutions). You can even bind your shiny new snippet to a key combination, as explained both [in this forum post](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1721) and [in this article](http://webtempest.com/sublime-text-2-how-to-create-snippets/)  (scroll down).

Make a new snippet with this as its content:

```
<snippet>
<content><![CDATA[
    ${SELECTION/(^[\d]+) (.+) ([\d]+)/['$1', '$2$3'],/g}
]]></content>
</snippet>
```

Save the snippet with whatever name suits your fancy. Now, after pasting, select all of your recently pasted data, split it into lines with `Ctrl+Shift+L`, then open the Command Palette with `Ctrl+Shift+P` and type in the snippet name you chose. Press `Enter`, et voilà! Your mysterious data table has been formatted as an array.

Of course, you'll have to edit the regular expression segment of the snippet (`(^[\d]+) (.+) ([\d]+)`) in the case that your input isn't as rigorous as your example text is. [Regexpal](http://regexpal.com/) can help.

Comment: Thank you I have a basic regex [here](http://www.debuggex.com/r/eN2Pqsq-5QDEBO0X/0) and for some reason sublime takes the input and seems to be deleting it instead using this snippet code `<![CDATA[
${$SELECTION/(\d{7})(\s)([A-Z].*)/['$1', '$3'],/g}
]]>`

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more generic solution that splits up an array on space.

```
<snippet>
<content><![CDATA[
[${SELECTION/\s*(\S+)\s*/'$1',/g}]
]]></content>
</snippet>
```